# How to use a Certificate in a Winforms Application to Authenticate a User?

Tags: c#, sql-server, certificate, azure-sql-database, x509

I have a Winforms Application that connects to both On-Premise SQL Server and Azure DB instances. It is multi-tenanted and I want to use a certificate and password combination on the host pc's to authenticate the user.

That is to say that the user needs to have both the certifiate and a password to access the database.

I intend to use Column Level Encryption with SQL Server/Azure DB to protect the data and Row Level security to isolate the tenants.

Access to row data will be via the users SID from Active Directory.

What is the best way of achieving this? Is this good practice?

Answer (score 0):

First: Welcome to StackOverflow

Your problem clearly needs an Architectural Solution.
You might want to look into a pattern called [StrategyPattern](https://exceptionnotfound.net/strategy-the-daily-design-pattern/).
A StrategyPattern will most likely fit your Approach because you can design your app to having two classes that handle Authentification for your database access. The most simple design would be using an simple Interface (lets call it `IDatabaseAuthentificator`). Now you have a flag somewhere (for example in the app.config) that decides what kind of database and what kind of Authentification the app should use.

So when you are trying to connect to a Database you will first read the `ConnectionString` and then this flag.